# nginx - The local domain is not working. Instead, localhost works

Tags: nginx

I am using windows 10.

In the file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts I wrote **127.0.0.1 myadmin.com**

Then I set up nginx:

```
    http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;

        server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  myadmin.com;

            location ~ \.php$ {
                root           html/myadmin.com;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include        fastcgi_params;
            }

        }

    }
```

When I run nginx, myadmin.com doesn't work **403 Forbidden**. Instead http://localhost/index.php works.

How to make myadmin.com work?